# Excel VBA -- Find first occurrence of any value in column A, then insert value of column B into column C (same row)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA script for a weekly chore.  Here is my data:

[image: IMG1]

I run a macro that clears out the values of column C.  Then i have to find the first occurrence of every unique value in Column A.  When I find the first occurrence, I write in the same row of Column C "=Column B" just for that row.  Basically, I'm trying to say, "A4 is the first occurrence of a unique value; therefore C4=B4."  I can't do a simple IF() function and drag it down, because the rest of column C needs to stay truly blank (it's referenced by an IF(NOT(ISBLANK)) function).

I'm new to VBA, and unfortunately recording what I did, did not capture my actual intent.  This was the macro, which doesn't seem efficient:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

    Range("C8").Select
    Application.Left = 3591.25
    Application.Top = 268
    Windows("Copy of OPS_schedule_6.xlsm").Activate
    Application.Left = 3451.75
    Application.Top = 163
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Alpha"
    Range("C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Bravo"
    Range("C4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    Range("C5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Charlie"
    Range("C8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    Range("C9").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used a formula such as

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,B1,"del")
```

You could clear the `del`s with Find & Select or, since you have tagged this VBA, with:

```
 Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 2).ClearContents
```